# What is the appropriate response of someone outside a Muslim country during a war?

Tags: war, politics, islamic-countries

I have seen this question on the Judaism.StackExchange: [What is the appropriate response of someone outside Israel during a war?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22316/what-is-the-appropriate-response-of-someone-outside-israel-during-a-war)

Jewish people living outside Israel feel responsibility to help the cruel regime that fired the war unfairly and very far from basics of humanity. Muslims can also ask the same question, to be at least a Muslim, as prophet Muhammad (PBUH) said:

> مَن اَصبَحَ وَ لَم یَهتَمَ بامُورالمُسلِمین فَلَیسَ بمُسلِم
>
> The one who does not care the Muslims affairs is not a Muslim

So I want to make the same question: What is the appropriate response of someone outside a Muslim country during a war? Please verify both cases of Muslims being attacked by non-Muslims (like the case of Palastine or Myanmar) or a war between two Muslim countries.

Comment: Make Du'a. We underestimate the power of Du'a.

Comment: What is the source of the hadith you quoted?

Answer (score 1):

They should make Dua' for them, for Dua' is a very powerful worship, those who make Dua' for their brothers and sisters while they not know it there is an Angel who will pray the same for you, [Source](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1495).  Other than this there is little one can do for Muslim countries at war.  To clarify a bit, there is no such thing as Muslim countries only countries whos majority are Muslim.  One can always donate money to help the Muslims who are needy in those countries, in other words to help those injured and to help those who need maintenance due to the war.  But the most important thing is Dua, make Dua, Make Dua, and don't stop.  Allah Says:

> و قال ربكم ادعوني أستجب لكم
>
> And your Lord says, "Call upon Me; I will respond to you."
>
> [Surat Ghafir Ayah 60](http://quran.com/40/60)